# FileNotFoundException when running sample test SparseSparseDrmTimer with Mahout

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mahout

I followed https://github.com/apache/mahout#building-from-source instructions. Everything went well. Scala shell starts with Mahout.

Now I am trying to perform sample test described in article:

```
scala> :load /home/<andy>/apache/mahout/examples
                               /bin/SparseSparseDrmTimer.mscala

scala> timeSparseDRMMMul(1000,1000,1000,1,.02,1234L)
```

But I am getting:

```
FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.61:42929/jars/mahout-spark_2.10-0.13.1-SNAPSHOTspark_$%7Bspark.compat.version%7D.jar
```

When I look into Mahout home dir, this file is there: mahout-spark_2.10-0.13.1-SNAPSHOTspark_${spark.compat.version}.jar

Does any one know why it is not found and how I can make Mohout to find it?

I am on fresh Ubuntu 16.04, all other software versions are as described in article.

Answer (score 1):

After adding: `-Dspark.compat.version=1.6.3`

and building Mahout with command:

```
mvn clean install -Pviennacl -Phadoop2 -Dspark.compat.version=1.6.3 -DskipTests
```

test passed. Tutorial is missing this in Maven command sample.

Comment: I would suggest running off of the last stable 0.13.0 release rather than the bleeding edge nightlies at them moment.  The mahout PMC is actively working on a 0.13.1 release, so the `0.13.1-SNAPSHOT` will be moving quickly and ahead of the docs.